# DomDocument parse Newline works with span but not img

Tags: php, xml, dom, newline

See here: https://ideone.com/bjs3IC

Why does the newline correctly display with the `span`s but not `img`s ?

```
<?php
    outputImages();
    outputSpans();




    function outputImages(){
        $html = "<div class='test'>
                    <pre>
                    <img src='http://d...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/5x5/000/fff'>
                    <img src='http://d...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/5x5/000/fff'>
                    <img src='http://d...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/5x5/000/fff'>
                    </pre>
                </div>";
        getHtml($html);
    }


    function outputSpans(){
        $html = "<div class='test'>
                    <pre>
                    <span>a</span>
                    <span>b</span>
                    <span>c</span>
                    </pre>
                </div>";
        getHtml($html);
    }


    function getHtml($html){
        $doc = new DOMDocument;
        $doc->loadhtml($html);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
        $tags = $xpath->query('//div[@class="test"]');
        print(get_inner_html($tags[0]));
    }


    function get_inner_html( $node ) {
        $innerHTML= '';
        $children = $node->childNodes;
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child );
        }

        return $innerHTML;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DOMDocument::loadHTML` function has a second `options` parameter. It appears like the `LIBXML_NOBLANKS` is (at least one of) the default values there.

You can use

```
$doc->loadhtml($html, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

To override that default value and your code will work the same for the two samples.

p.s.
Not sure why you use

```
print(get_inner_html($tags[0]));
```

The `$tags` variable is a `DOMNodeList`, so you should use `$tags->item(0)` to get the first tag.

Your complete code should look like this:

```
outputImages();
outputSpans();

function outputImages() {
    $html = "<div class='test'>
                <pre>
                <img src='http://d...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/5x5/000/fff'>
                <img src='http://d...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/5x5/000/fff'>
                <img src='http://d...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/5x5/000/fff'>
                </pre>
            </div>";
    getHtml($html);
}

function outputSpans() {
    $html = "<div class='test'>
                <pre>
                <span>a</span>
                <span>b</span>
                <span>c</span>
                </pre>
            </div>";
    getHtml($html);
}

function getHtml($html) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $tags = $xpath->query('//div[@class="test"]');
    print(get_inner_html($tags->item(0)));
}

function get_inner_html( $node ) {
    $innerHTML= '';
    $children = $node->childNodes;
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child );
    }
    return $innerHTML;
}
```